# Example of writing byte array of different size sequentially to a blob in Windows Azure

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I've been trying to find a good example on this but I must be searching for the wrong things.
Here's what I wish to do:

- One process writes byte arrays of different size to a blob sequentially (no need for any concurrency checks or anything like that). Each byte array is committed to the blob at each write
- Other processes reads from the blob from starting at different positions but reads sequentially after that

Basically what I'm trying to describe is a transaction log. Any links to good resources or code samples to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Brent Stineman has an interesting technique which he used for a client that he explains on [Cloud Cover Show](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Cloud+Cover/Episode-57-Windows-Azure-Page-Blobs-with-Brent-Stineman)