# Writing application log files in azure blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Currently I'm logging in blob storage by creating a List of string that i want to log and when the number of strings in the list crosses a number convert the list to a byte array and calling CloudBlockBlob.UploadFromStream..

I have recently come to know that I can also write to the blob directly one line at a time without creating the list of log-lines [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn745862.aspx).The article shows 'await destinationStream.WriteAsync'.

I would sincerely appreciate if someone could guide me as to how to shift towards this style..

I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401725/example-of-writing-byte-array-of-different-size-sequentially-to-a-blob-in-window) asked a couple of years back but no answers to the same as well..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you are rolling your own logging instead of using Azure Diagnostics?  You can post unique messages to the diagnostics log azure table

[Guid To Starting Azure Diagnostics](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-diagnostics/)

Comment: These logs are not diagnostic logs .. but analytics logs for use in HDInsight

Answer (score 0):

You can output the standard Trace to the WADLogsTable with the following:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="false" indentsize="4" xdt:Transform="Insert">
        <listeners>
            <add name="AzureDiagnostics" type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        </listeners>
    </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```